# Ubuntu 16.04 systemd in degraded state because dns-clean service failed

Tags: systemd

On Ubuntu 16.04.2 I noticed that systemd is in degraded state (systemctl status) after some uptime or after wake from suspend, because dns-clean.service failed.

```
dns-clean.service has

ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir /var/run/pppconfig
```

When I remove /var/run/pppconfig directory which is empty, the service can be started successfully (systemctl start dns-clean.service) and systemd is in running mode.

The directory /var/run/pppconfig is not supposed to exist when the system wants to start the service, so why is it still here ?

There is a Debian bug report about this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=826040

Answer (score 2):

the command `mkdir` return an error if the directory exist.
You can avoid this error using `mkdir -p`. just edit `/lib/systemd/system/dns-clean.service` and ajust the line `ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/pppconfig`